# Checking if an object 'is' of a generic type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

And I want to add an extension to SwiftUI's `View` protocol that changes behaviour based on the actual type of view:

```
extension View {
    func something() {
        switch self { 
            case is Text: // Do stuff.
            case is Button<AnyView>: // Do other stuff
            default: // Do other other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `is Button<AnyView>` case is not met for any `Button` type. I cannot *not* specify a generic type, and I also cannot specify `Any`. How do I check if an object `is` of a generic type?

(I cannot use additional, more specific `extension`s to override this function, apparently.)

Comment: Invert your thinking. Instead of having a function with a switch, create a function on `Text` and on `Button`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot use additional, more specific extensions to override this function, apparently."? Does the stuff you do in each `case` involve casting to that type? If so, an extension is really what you need.

Comment: @Sweeper @Sulthan I was trying to override the one from the `extension`, which isn't really feasible. It turns out this was basically a ridiculous thing to try and do anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not considering the purpose of this, if you have limited set of buttons something like the following could be used

```
extension View {
    func something() -> Self {
        switch self {
            case is Text: // Do stuff.
                print("> text")
            case is Button<Text>: // Do other stuff
                    print("> text button")
            case is Button<Image>: // Do other stuff
                    print("> image button")
            default: // Do other other stuff
                print("> other")
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, one might make the method generic if so wished.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you would want to use `Button<?>`, in Swift it's not possible, but you can emulate it.

1. Create a protocol `protocol AnyButton {}`
2. Now let all buttons implement this protocol: `extension Button: AnyButton {}`
3. Now you can easily do what you intended to do:

   ```
   switch self {
     case is Text: ...
     case is AnyButton: ...
   }
   ```